# PHP form XSS vulnerability

Tags: php, security

I'd like to ask if this PHP/HTML code has any flaws which can be exploited by the potential aggressor:

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
<input type='text' name='foo' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo']); ?>' /> 
<input type='submit' value='bar' />
</form>
```

I'm aware that it can be exploited by calling script like this http://foo.bar/baz.php/'><script>alert('xss')</script><foo' and

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

should be replaced with

```
<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> or <?php echo htmlspecialshars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
```

Are there any other possible ways to conduct XSS attack on this piece of code? If so, how can I secure this form?

@Update: Ok, I've just found another possible attack - entering code like ' onmouseover='alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83,33)); (with the apostrophe in the beginning) into the text field, which causes simple 'XSS!' alert. It can be avoided by changing `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo']); ?>` to `<?php echo str_replace('\'', '&#39;', htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo'])); ?>`

Comment: You've answered your own question... Though I think `__FILE__` is the preferred way, rather than `$_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]` although I may be mistaken. Only other thing I can think to suggest is that you take a look at `filter_input()` for that post variable that you also never verified was set.

Comment: Amendment: `$_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ]` is the preferred way, not `__FILE__`, not sure what I was thinking... Though the latter should work too.

Answer (score 2):

For single-quoted attributes, use `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES)`.

Depending on what this does, you might want to implement some sort of protection against CSRF attacks.

You might also want to check `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

Other than that, this code seems reasonable.